# Error - Returning JSON along with HTTP status code error JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/data/services")
public Response  DiscoverDevice(BlockDevsPost blockdevice) {

    for (DeviceIdentifier device : blockdevice.getDevice()) {
        String dev = device.Device();
        System.out.println("DEVICE "+ dev);
        if (dev == null || dev.equals("")){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Device cannot be null or empty.").build();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error when fired POST from REST Client when `dev` is null. I am not able to get JSON and this error is thrown:

> Unexpected character (D) at position 0. Device Identifier cannot be null or empty.

Where D in Device Identifier marked as Red which means it is not returning JSON as response.

Comment: I am not able to get JSON an this error is thrown when dev is null

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: When dev is sent as null from REST Client . It will throw the error as HTTP Bad Request error . But the response message I am getting -  Unexpected character (D) at position 0. Device Identifier cannot be null or empty. where D in Device Identifier marked as Red which means it is not returning JSON as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is expecting to get JSON but you have set a plain string in the Response entity and `application/json` as content-type. You need to return a valid JSON. For example

```
return Response
           .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
           .entity("{\"error\":\"Device cannot be null or empty.\"}")
           .build();
```

You can also build the json response string using your preferred mapper  (you will need to add a dependency). This is an example using Jackson

**Jackson using API**

```
ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
objectNode.put("error", "Device cannot be null or empty.");
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(objectNode);
```

**Jackson using POJO**

```
class ErrorBean{
   private String error;
   //getters and setters
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ErrorBeanerrorBean = new ErrorBean();
errorBean.setError ("Device cannot be null or empty.");
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(errorBean);
```

You can also return POJO from your service method and let the JAX-RS implementation to convert them to JSON (this means change the response type). See https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: Worked !. Thank-you.

Comment: Escape of double quotes doesnt look proper. Is there any other way to write the wrapper to accept the JSON Object.

Comment: You can build the JSON string using a mapper library: Jackson, Gson, jettison... See an example in the updated answer.